# Equivalent view of "user_types" (ORACLE) in POSTGRESQL?

Tags: postgresql

Please can you tell me what is the table/view that stores informations about created types in Postgresql.

In Oracle the view is called "user_types" but i can't find the equivalent in Postgresql

Rq : the view pg_type isn't the one. that one stores information about data types. But i need information about created types.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

`pg_type` **will** contain the types you created using `CREATE TYPE`

Oracle's `user_types` only contains the one the current user owns, so the equivalent in Postgres is

```
select *
from pg_type
where typowner = current_user::regrole;
```

To get the attributes defined in the type, you will need to use `pg_class` and join it to `pg_attribute`

The views from `information_schema` might be easier to use for this:

```
select udt.user_defined_type_schema,
       udt.user_defined_type_name, 
       att.attribute_name, 
       att.data_type, 
       att.is_nullable,
       att.character_maximum_length, 
       att.numeric_precision, 
       att.numeric_scale, 
       att.datetime_precision
from information_schema.user_defined_types udt
  join information_schema.attributes att 
    on att.udt_name = udt.user_defined_type_name 
   and att.udt_schema = udt.user_defined_type_schema
order by att.ordinal_position
```

Comment: thank you very much ! but i want to get the attributes of the created_type and i don't think they are stored in "pg_type" view :(

Comment: @MohamedmehdiEllouze: you should have mentioned that in your question. You can either join to `pg_class` to `pg_attribute` but `information_schema` is easier to use. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

`pg_type` does store user created types:

```
CREATE TYPE compfoo AS (f1 int, f2 text);

select * from pg_type where typname = 'compfoo';
 oid   | typname 
--------+---------
 128397 | compfoo
```

Comment: thank you very much ! but i want to get the attributes of the created_type and i don't think they are stored in "pg_type" view :( . In your example where can i find the "f1" and "f2" and there type types int & text ? in which view

Comment: Read the [pg_type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-type.html) page. There are a host of attributes shown there.